Multiprocessing as slow as sequential
def blend(s1_num, ind_f, ind_t, connection):
    s2_num = 1.0 - s1_num
    blended_array = []
    blended_vec = []
    lt = len(template)

    for i in range(ind_f, ind_t):    
        p = np.array(nlp.vocab[s1[i]].vector)
        o = np.array(nlp.vocab[s2[i]].vector)


        p *= s1_num
        o *= s2_num

        blended_vec = p + o


        ms = nlp.vocab.vectors.most_similar(np.asarray([blended_vec]), n=16)
        words = [nlp.vocab.strings[w] for w in ms[0][0]]

    
    
        blended_array = blended_array + [words[15].lower()]

    
    connection.send(blended_array)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn1, conn2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    modified_array = []

    process1 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 0, 50, conn2))
    process2 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 50, 100, conn2))
    process3 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 100, 150, conn2))
    process4 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 150, 218, conn2))

    process1.start()

    modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()

    process2.start()

    modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()

    process3.start()

    modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()

    process4.start()

    modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()
    process1.join()
    process2.join()
    process3.join()
    process4.join()

    print_arrayed_text(modified_array)

I am writing a program that does some spacy on a text, and it involves processing vectors of 300 in an array of length 218. I'm splitting an array into 4 parts and am trying to do processing on each part in parallel then joining the array afterword. Any idea why its as slow as sequential?

You're starting each sub-process after the previous one is done working.  Have you tried starting them all before gathering the results?

numpy operations can internally use threaded logic, so it may actually be slower when multiprocessing!

@Anon Coward How might i start them before?

Any reason you don't want to use multiprocessing.Pool and just use pool.map() for your use case?

Amdahl's Law?

This:

modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()

waits for an object to become ready on the connection, which effectively waits for the process to complete before moving on.
Instead you should start all your processes first, then get the results as they come in.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn1, conn2 = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    modified_array = []

    process1 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 0, 50, conn2))
    process2 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 50, 100, conn2))
    process3 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 100, 150, conn2))
    process4 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 150, 218, conn2))>

    process1.start()
    process2.start()
    process3.start()
    process4.start()
    
    modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()
    modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()
    modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()
    modified_array = modified_array + conn1.recv()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()
    process3.join()
    process4.join()

    print_arrayed_text(modified_array)

There is a potential issue here however depending on the size of your array and the size of the underlying buffer given to the underlying OS pipe. It can cause an error sending very large arrays as noted in the documentation, but more importantly, pipes may not have any sort of protection against corruption due to simultaneous writes from multiple child processes finishing at the same time. For this reason, I would use a Queue instead:
def blend(s1_num, ind_f, ind_t, connection):
    ...
    connection.put(blended_array)  # Queue uses "put" and "get" rather than "send" and "receive"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    modified_array = []

    process1 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 0, 50, conn2))
    process2 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 50, 100, conn2))
    process3 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 100, 150, conn2))
    process4 = Process(target=blend, args=(0.25, 150, 218, conn2))>

    process1.start()
    process2.start()
    process3.start()
    process4.start()
    
    modified_array = modified_array + q.get()  # Queue uses "put" and "get" rather than "send" and "receive"
    modified_array = modified_array + q.get()
    modified_array = modified_array + q.get()
    modified_array = modified_array + q.get()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()
    process3.join()
    process4.join()

    print_arrayed_text(modified_array)


...mind, there's a larger issue insofar as the OP's code is using numpy, which generally uses threads under the hood; so there's a good chance multiprocessing will just slow things down by creating contention among resources that were already fully utilized.

It really depends on the situation.. I find the default blas for pre-built windows binaries (what most newbies are using fwiw) actually use single threading in many cases.
